# UWP Windows Store App showing 'Redeem a code'

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps

I have created and uploaded/certified an application to the Windows Store, the app works perfectly but I wanted it to be a public/hidden application that can only be found with a provided link.  So i setup the product accordingly in my submission.  However all i get when i click the 'live' app link is a blue button that says 'redeem a code'.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

PS: I've added a minimum / required specification and the store page still says its 'not compatiable'.  Which it most definitely is.  It may still be related to the settings I have here, does anyone know the 'simplest' options for this page that works?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Added image of Configuration and the result (green square in store)
[image]

Comment: What have you set by -'So i setup the product accordingly in my submission.'? Could you please tell me more details about how you configured your app?

Comment: Under 'Pricing and Availability'  I have set the Visibility as 'Public Audience' but the discoverability as 'Make this product available but no discoverable in the store' and 'Direct link only'

Comment: According to the document:[Make this product available but not discoverable in the Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/choose-visibility-options#make-this-product-available-but-not-discoverable-in-the-store), you are getting the behavior like you set it as **Stop acquisition** instead of **Directly link only**. Could you please double check the setting in Partner Center?

Comment: Yes its set to 'Direct Link Only'  See image i've added to the original post, and the result in the Store.

Comment: It's strange behavior. Could you please open a free [support ticket](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support/)? Choose to Contact us, select Dashboard for Topic and select App submissions for issue type. 
 The store team could check your app and contact you via email.

Comment: Hi Roy, we did create a support ticket and unfortunately they were very little help.  This is the last email we got... "I would recommend contacting Frontline support for this issue as until we can bypass the error of the specifications not met engineering will point to the following. I recommend using the link down below to see if they can assist with downloading the app or even bypass the current setting and if any further issue persists we can definitely assist further.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us"

Comment: If you reset all the configurations and then changed it to direct link only, will it get the correct behavior?